# d3.layout.treemap in d3 version 4

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have the following data to generate treemap:

```
var treemap_data = {
"name": "Max",
"value": 100,
"children": [
    {
        "name": "Sylvia",
        "value": 75,
        "children": [
            {"name": "craig", "value": 25},
            {"name": "Robin", "value": 25},
            {"name": "Anna", "value": 25}
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "David",
        "value": 75,
        "children": [
            {"name": "Jeff", "value": 25},
            {"name": "Buffy", "value": 25}
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Sylvia",
        "value": 75
    }
]
}
```

using d3 version 3.5.6 I am able to use d3 layout:

```
var treemap_data = d3.layout.treemap()
  .size([500, 500])
  .nodes(data)
```

but it does not work in d3 version 4.2.3.

Comment: in d3 V4  d3.layout.treemap is replace with d3.treemap refer this for more details
https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#hierarchies-d3-hierarchy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per new syntax

```
var treemap_data = d3.tree().size([500, 500]);
```

Here is the treemap of your your data using D3 V4.

https://jsfiddle.net/n4m1r8nb/58/